# Autofilling and submitting forms programmatically

Tags: php, javascript

I am wondering if it is possible for my PHP script to navigate to a web page that has a web form on it, fill out the fields and click submit without human intervention.

Is there a way to scan a page, extract the input text fields and supply a value?

Or is there a piece of software that can do this, doesn't matter if it is not PHP.

Comment: You can set a websocket, and then have javascript code at the client side that gathers the form datas and do "document.getElementById('mysubmitbutton').click();" to submit the form or programatically gather the datas from the form fields. Is that what you want to do ?

Answer (score 3):

curl is what you are looking for, look at this link http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools for automated testing of webpages, such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use curl, unless there is csrf protection on the form.

> php script to navigate to a web page that has a web form on it, fill
>   out the fields and click submit without human intervention.

If you have some time and want to try a fringe scripting language out:

Back in the day (highschool) we wrote autoit scripts to click google ads and got our accounts suspended =(

Autoit can control the cursor and keyboard input and do repetitive tasks

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) is probably your best choice.

In my experience, Perl's WWW::Mechanize is easier to use. If you have experience with Perl, you may wish to use it.